# Emissão de NFe por aplicativo Android

Tags: android, nfe

Boa tarde,

Tenho que iniciar um projeto onde vou integrar em um aplicativo Android de vendas a **opção de emitir uma NFe**.
Qual a melhor forma de iniciar esse processo, seria realizar todo o processo no *Android* ou através de um *Web Service*?
Existe alguma biblioteca ou API que auxilia no desenvolvimento?

Answer (score 4):

Eu acredito que o Web Service é a melhor opção, pois para fazer a requisição para NFE vc precisa ter o certificado instalado, caso fizesse isto no android teria que gerir o certificado em cada aparelho que o app estiver instalado, no WebService você consegue montar a pilha para requisições simultâneas *(ou quando der indisponibilidade no servidor da receita ...) e gerencia o certificado num único lugar.

Comment: Entendi, obrigada! Você teria algum exemplo de WebService em java ??

Answer (score 2):

Depende o escopo do projeto, se for desenvolver para para pequenas empresas onde só um dispositivo irá emitir nota, faça tudo no ambiente android, caso vários dispositivos emitirão nf-e use um webservice, como o Bartolomeu falou o gerenciamento de pilhas de requisição vai ficar mais fácil desenvolver.

Caso for usar PHP pra desenvolver o webservice da uma olhadinha nesse repositório do github.
https://github.com/nfephp-org

Créditos e site oficial
http://www.nfephp.org/pt/latest/

Comment: Entendi, obrigada! Você teria algum exemplo de WebService em java ??

Answer (score 0):

monte um servidor PHP instale a API NFEPHP, com ele você não precisará instalar o certificado digital no app só no servidor.

uma vez criado e configurado o servidor web PHP com a API NFEPHP rodando e considerando que vc possui conhecimentos em java para ANDROID/IOS, comece com webview.

boa sorte...